# A command to call a terminal (not a hotkey)

Tags: command-line

In krusader there is a command "konsole" to call a konsole application. But what if I want to call the standard terminal, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coomand for termial in Ubuntu is `gnome-terminal`. Hope that's what you've asked.

Comment: and yes and no. It runs gnome-terminal. How do I run xubuntu (xcfe) terminal?

Comment: Oh dear! How many DEs do you have? Try `xfce4-terminal` in Xubuntu, and `lxterminal` in Lubuntu.